# How to download a file in iOS (Ionic 2/3)?

Tags: ios, file, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to download a file and save that file in iOS. I am using [ionic-native-file](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) plugin to achieve this. The file has been download but i could not find that file in the device.

```
filewrite = (): void => {
    let transfer = this.fileTransfer.create();
    let path = "";
    let dir_name = 'Download';
    let file_name = "Sample.pdf";

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          path = this.file.documentsDirectory;

          this.file.writeFile(path,file_name,this.pdfSrc).then((entry) => {
            this.showAlert("download completed");
          }, (error) => {
            this.showAlert("Download Failed.");
          }).catch(err=>{
            this.showAlert("Download Failed catch.");
            this.showAlert(err.message);

          });
        }
      )
    }
  };
```

Download completed alert shows and the downloaded path is:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6DE22F30-5806-4393-830A-14C8A1F320BE/Library/Cloud/Sample.pdf

But i could not find that location in the device. Then, i google and saw [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).

> cordova.file.documentsDirectory - Files private to the app, but that
>   are meaningful to other application (e.g. Office files). Note that for
>   OSX this is the user's ~/Documents directory. (iOS, OSX)

So, i can't see the file actually as it is private to the application. Then i saw in the same link:

[image]

So, i tried with the both preference in my config.xml but nothing happened.

Is there any approach to download the file iOS or to dropbox or anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled to find the right directory to save to on different platforms with this cordova plugin too.  I landed on using `file.externalRootDirectory` on Android, and `file.cacheDirectory` on iOS.

The right location likely depends on what you intend to do with the file.  In my case I just needed it stored short-term so I can open it using the user's native PDF reader.

Comment: Can i directly save the file to dropbox or google drive?

Comment: My intent is to save the file in iPad and i will open and view the file whenever i want.

Comment: In theory you can save the file wherever you want.  Assuming you are in control of the saving, you could save it on your own back-end server, or a service like dropbox/google.  You'd just have to work out the security/access side of it, then make a request for it whenever you need to view it.  Obviously the user would need Internet access to re-obtain the file in this situation.

Comment: Where do you find the file in filesystem of iPad when you are saving in CacheDirectory? Can you locate the file?

Comment: I've never tried viewing it directly from the iOS device (e.g. browsing to it somehow).  I've personally just opened it programmatically after downloading it.